# R split strings in vector with different lengths

Tags: r, string, split, vectorization

I have a problem in R trying to split a vector of strings into a vector of vectors. If anyone can help me, please I am stuck.

I have:

```
V <- c("AAAAA", "AAAAA BBBBB", "CCCCC DDDDD")
```

Using strsplit I get:

```
s <- strplit(v)
s
[[1]]
[1] "AAAAA"

[[2]]
[1] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"

[[3]]
[1] "CCCCC" "DDDDD"
```

However I cannot access these to compare them. I would like something like:

```
 s
[1] "AAAAA"
[2] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"
[3] "CCCCC" "DDDDD"
```

I would then like to see if the elements of each of these vectors are included in my validation vector (like c("AAAAA", "BBBBB, "CCCCC") and return a boolean at the end (TRUE if all elements are in, FALSE otherwise).
For now my problem is getting those vectors. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `tidyverse`, you could go with

```r
V <- c("AAAAA", "AAAAA BBBBB", "CCCCC DDDDD")
validation <- c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC")

library(purrr)
library(stringr)
str_split(V, pattern = " ") %>% 
  map_lgl(~all(.x %in% validation))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You could also include this with `dplyr` to obtain a clear summary of which vector is validated or not.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=F)
data_frame(V) %>%
  mutate(validate = str_split(V, pattern = " ") %>% 
           map_lgl(~all(.x %in% validation)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>             V validate
#>         <chr>    <lgl>
#> 1       AAAAA     TRUE
#> 2 AAAAA BBBBB     TRUE
#> 3 CCCCC DDDDD    FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works indeed! I am not familiar will all the packages you used but I definitely will get up to speed!

Answer (score 3):

strsplit returns a list you can go trough it by using lapply with a custom function

```
V <- c("AAAAA", "AAAAA BBBBB", "CCCCC DDDDD")
s <- strsplit(V, split = " ")
val <- c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC")

lapply(s, function(x) x %in% val)
```

you can access list elements like this:

```
s[[1]]
s[[2]]
```

to check if all elements are present in val

```
all <- lapply(s, function(x) sum(x %in% val) == length(val))
#output 
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

to convert this list to a vector

```
all <- unlist(all)
```

to return the original elements from V

```
v[all]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had thought of that be my problem is then accessing the final result. as in getting someting in the from c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) and dealing with missing values .

Answer (score 0):

R does not have a vector of vectors.

To emulate this behavior you would usually use `list`s and the `apply`-family.

```r
input_vector <- c("AAAAA", "AAAAA BBBBB", "CCCCC DDDDD")

# split the string like you did
s <- strsplit(input_vector, split = " ")
s
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "AAAAA"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "CCCCC" "DDDDD"

# create a vector with conditions that wee look for
validation_vector <- c("AAAAA", "BBBBB")

# create a matrix of matches
res_matrix <- sapply(s, function(s_part) {
  validation_vector %in% s_part
})

# check if all validation_vector elements are true for a given input_vector-string
# by applying the 'all'-function over each column ("are all elements for a given column TRUE?")
res_vector <- apply(res_matrix, 2, all)
# for aesthetic purposes: add the name of the initial input_vector again
names(res_vector) <- input_vector

# display the result
res_vector
#>       AAAAA AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD 
#>       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `*apply` family of functions. For example, using `sapply` to apply the `strsplit` function to each of your list elements you get

```
vs <- sapply(V, strsplit, split = " ")

vs

$AAAAA
[1] "AAAAA"

$`AAAAA BBBBB`
[1] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"

$`CCCCC DDDDD`
[1] "CCCCC" "DDDDD"
```

Further to check against you `validation` vector you can do

```
validation <- c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC")
vs_in_val <- sapply(vs, `%in%`, validation) 

vs_in_val

$AAAAA
[1] TRUE

$`AAAAA BBBBB`
[1] TRUE TRUE

$`CCCCC DDDDD`
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried apply extensively but ultimately if failed. I basically want to avoid that list element.

Answer (score 0):

strsplit can help you do it if you combine it with 'lapply'.

```
V <- c("AAAAA", "AAAAA BBBBB", "CCCCC DDDDD")
s <- strsplit(V," ")
sapply(s,function(x) return (sum(x %in% c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC"))/length(x)))
[1] 1.0 1.0 0.5
```

If the result returns 0,then it indicates that there is none of elements in your validation vectors.

If 1, all of elements in your validation vector.

if between 0 and 1,there is some of elements in your validation vector.